# Ask for some advices for WebPart internationalization

Tags: internationalization, web-parts

Recently,I am handling a solution for WebPart internationalization,but I am not familiar with the culture or habits in different regions.So I am asking for some information if you are glad to help.
  Suppose I am a different person in another region,for example,a German.I am using the SharePoint,which is a German edition.So,
  1) What's the input habit of me?
  For example,if I need to input "10000",will I input "10.000,00" or just "10000"?Which is frequent to the user?
  2) How to handle the "Date" and "Time" format?
  I think it's better if I can select the date or time instead of inputing the date or time string.
  3) Any information that you think will be helpful to me?
  That is very kind of you,thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I am not sure how you want to handle i18n, but I am assuming that you want to do this on the client side.

In this case, I can recommend using [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) for formatting (both numerical values and date/time could be handled this way).
As for parsing dates (that is handling dates provided by user), there is actually even easier way - just use [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) with [valid regional script](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/). Obtaining Date object is as easy as calling Datepicker's [getDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate) method.

Comment: You really help me.You are right,I want to do this on the client side,and one more question,in javascript,how to handle the string that output to the different culture clients?

Comment: @Xiaodan Mao: I am sorry, but I am really unable to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I am sorry to make you confused,for example,I want to display some words in a webPart,so if the user is an American,he should see the words in English,while the Chinese should see the words in Chinese.

Comment: @Xiaodan Mao: I guess you are asking how to provide Localization. Globalize contains localize() function which let you do that. However, you will need to create translation object and valid Localization on the server side (the easiest way to do that is to simply let web page output script with the translations and the locale [known as Culture in both .Net and Globalize] ). This is fairly "standard" approach to localizing client-side scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I've known that Globalize already contains a solution for i18n,and I can directly use some common functions.The resource files will also be a good help.